# How to configure nginx proxy to get only first the fastest response from the servers

Tags: nginx

Exist some remote servers with same static files

```
http://site1.com/image.png
http://site2.com/image.png
http://site3.com/image.png
```

For example, all this servers are unreliable and can give response only after few seconds.

How can I configure my nginx proxy to get the first fastest response from only one of them?

I know about upstream module, but there are only consecutive requests examples.

Is there configuration to do it with parallel concurrent requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken about the way nginx operates.

Requests are processed neither one after another nor simultaneously (which is impossible). nginx reacts on events corresponding to differents stages during requests processing, which kind of multiplexes them.

The [upstream](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream) module (and its directive of the same name) you point to is the way to go, along with the [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive.

The center of your focus might be the [`$upstream_response_time`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_response_time) variable. As its name indicates, it stores response time of the upstream servers and might be dealt with to change the selection of the backend server nginx shall choose.

To do so, you can tweak your upstream servers group to add a weight to each [`server`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) and different flags to impact the default round-robin mechanism.

You can then change weights according to the response times you collected by generating files you include in your upstream servers group configuration. Note that changing the configuration will need nginx to be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This function exists in nginx commercial subscription least_time used upstream backend directive controls which of two response times is tracked: either the time to receive the response header (header) or the time to receive the full response (last_byte). you can read more about this here https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-nginx-plus-load-balancing-techniques/ example

```
upstream backend {
    least_time (header | last_byte);

    server web1;
    server web2;
    server web3;
}

server {
server_name www.example.com;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

or you can use $upstream_queue_time that keeps time of request spent in the upstream queue Times of several responses are separated by commas and colons like addresses in the $upstream_addr variable. you can read more about this here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_response_time

I am currently looking for same solution i found Nginx C module that expose Lua API to ngx_lua for Nginx upstreams you can read more here https://github.com/openresty/lua-upstream-nginx-module

if you found a beautiful solution please reply